# scilab call C function

Tags: c, call, scilab

I would like to call C function within scilab. I am trying to follow "call" convention but it does not work for me somehow therefore I am looking for help.

C function:

```
f1=['void add1(double a,double b,double *c)
     { *c=a+b; }'];

mputl(f1,'fun1.c')

ilib_for_link('add1','fun1.c',[],"c")
a=1.1;b=2.2;
c=call('add1',a,1,'d',b,2,'d','out',[1,1],3,'d');

disp(c)
```

f1 function should just add two real numbers and pass it by reference. The result is always out of range. 
Can you please help me point what I am doing wrong and how to correctly call C function within scilab?

Thank you.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If you make all arguments pointers, it works fine. Also don't forget to load the function by executing loader.sce

Working example:

```
f1=['void add1(double* a,double* b,double *c){ *c=*a+*b; }'];

mputl(f1,'fun1.c')

ilib_for_link('add1','fun1.c',[],"c")

a=1.1;
b=2.2;

exec loader.sce

[c] = call('add1', a, 1,'d', b,2,'d', 'out',[1,1],3,'d');

disp(c)
```